# Netty SMTP code - server side

Tags: java, netty

I looked in Netty 4.1 source code on SMTP codec and it appears is only for clients and not for server. Doing a google search I've found this post from May,26 2016 http://netty.io/news/2016/05/26/4-1-0-Final.html

> codec-smtp : Support for SMTP protocol (only client side atm).

We're in 2018 now, is there any implementation of SMTP protocol for server side or is it planned one in the near future?

Comment: I think you need to use a dedicated mail server like `James` if it has to be java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no smtp server side codec in netty yet as no-one contributed it and the core maintainers of the project itself also did not write one yet.

Answer (score 1):

I just started to work on something.
It's very basic and has a lot of missing pieces and it's a delivery" only SMTP system, but it's a start.

Feel free to have a look at: https://github.com/thomasmey/nsmtp